# Git: Rebase over a combination of commits

Tags: git

Let us assume that we have a commit history like this:

```
A---B---C    (master)
     \
      D---E  (branch)
```

We want to squash commits B and C to a combination of them B/C, and then we want to rebase the "branch" over the new combined commit, i.e., we want to obtain something like this:

```
A---(B/C)      (master)
       \
        D---E  (branch)
```

Is it possible to obtain?
Could you please suggest me a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do the following:

```
git checkout master
git rebase -i commit_A master
```

Where 'commit_A' is the hash of the commit A.

In the interactive session, select `squash` for the commit C.

It will create the following structure:

```
* 63de888 (HEAD, master) B/C
| * cd56322 (branch) E
| * 9cb2dd6 D
| * 544fa17 B
|/  
* 2fc2859 A
```

Then, rebase the branch:

```
git checkout branch
git rebase master
```

The result should look like this:

```
* a14e4d6 (HEAD, branch) E
* dc64709 D
* 63de888 (master) B/C
* 2fc2859 A
```

I used the following script to verify the steps:

```
#! /bin/bash

set -eu

create-commit () {
    touch $1
    git add $1
    git commit -m $1
}

mkdir 0
cd 0
git init

create-commit A
create-commit B

git checkout -b branch
create-commit D
create-commit E

git checkout master
create-commit C

git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate | grep .

commit_A=$(git log --all | grep -B4 '^    A' | head -n1)
commit_A=${commit_A#* }
echo $commit_A

git rebase -i $commit_A master
git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate | grep .

git checkout branch
git rebase master

git log --oneline --graph --all --decorate | grep .
gitk --all
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works :)

One thing that maybe could be helpful to others.
During some experiments today, I found that in the case in which the changes of "C" have not been committed yet, it is possible to perform a commit to amend "B" to obtain an amemded "B/C": this creates the same structure of that you pointed out after the first sqaush.
Then, as you suggested, the next step is that of rebasing branch over master.

Answer (score 0):

1. remember the hash of old B
2. mangle your master branch
3. `git checkout branch`
4. `git rebase --onto master <hash-from-step-1>`